# How to read data from Dynamically created textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I've some label and textbox created dynamically.

After user click "Save" button, i need to read all label and textbox in my Panel (panelFields) and get label.text and textbox.text to save it.

Problem is that looping through panelFields i don't get any controls.

This happens because of (i think) asp.net page lifecycle. So after clicking any button (Postback) , all that controls disappear.

This is my code where i create dynamic fields:

```
if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    panelFields.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<table cellpadding='6' cellspacing='6'>"));

                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        panelFields.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("  <tr>"));
                        panelFields.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("    <td style='vertical-align:top;font-weigth:bold;font-size:10pt;'>"));
                        string field_label = dr["field_label"].ToString();
                        string field_name  = dr["field_name"].ToString();
                        string field_type = dr["field_type"].ToString();
                        string field_width = dr["width"].ToString();
                        string field_height = dr["height"].ToString();

                        Label lbl = new Label();
                        lbl.Text = field_label;
                        lbl.ID = "lbl" + field_name;
                        panelFields.Controls.Add(lbl);

                        switch (field_type)
                        {
                            case "Text":
                                panelFields.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("  <td >"));
                                TextBox txt = new TextBox();
                                txt.Text = "";
                                txt.ID = "txt" + field_name;
                                Unit ut = new Unit(field_width);
                                txt.Width = ut;
                                ut = new Unit(field_height);
                                txt.Height = ut;
                                txt.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
                                panelFields.Controls.Add(txt);
                                panelFields.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("  </td>"));

                                break;
                            case "Number":
                                panelFields.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("  <td>"));
                                txt = new TextBox();
                                txt.Text = "";
                                txt.ID = "txt" + field_name;
                                ut = new Unit(field_width);
                                txt.Width = ut;
                                ut = new Unit(field_height);
                                txt.Height = ut;
                                txt.TextMode = TextBoxMode.Number;
                                panelFields.Controls.Add(txt);
                                panelFields.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("  </td>"));
                                break;
                            case "Date":
                                panelFields.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("  <td>"));
                                txt = new TextBox();
                                txt.Text = "";
                                txt.ID = "txt" + field_name;
                                ut = new Unit(field_width);
                                txt.Width = ut;
                                ut = new Unit(field_height);
                                txt.Height = ut;
                                txt.TextMode = TextBoxMode.Date;
                                panelFields.Controls.Add(txt);
                                panelFields.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("  </td>"));
                                break;
                            case "Time":
                                panelFields.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("  <td>"));
                                txt = new TextBox();
                                txt.Text = "";
                                txt.ID = "txt" + field_name;
                                 ut = new Unit(field_width);
                                txt.Width = ut;
                                ut = new Unit(field_height);
                                txt.Height = ut;
                                txt.TextMode = TextBoxMode.Time;
                                panelFields.Controls.Add(txt);
                                panelFields.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("  </td>"));
                                break;
                        }

                        panelFields.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</tr>"));
                    }
                    panelFields.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</table>"));
                }
```

And this is code where i try to get all labels and textboxes.

```
htmlAllFields = "<table cellspacing='4' cellpadding='4'";
            string _label="";
            string _value="";
            int counter = panelFields.Controls.Count;
            foreach (Control ctr in panelFields.Controls)
            {
                if (ctr is Label)
                {
                    Label lbl = (Label)ctr;
                    _label = lbl.Text;
                }
                if (ctr is TextBox)
                {
                    TextBox txt = (TextBox)ctr;
                    _value = txt.Text;
                }
                htmlAllFields = htmlAllFields + " <tr>";
                htmlAllFields = htmlAllFields + "  <td>";
                htmlAllFields = htmlAllFields + "    <b>" + _label + "</b>";
                htmlAllFields = htmlAllFields + "  </td>";
                htmlAllFields = htmlAllFields + "  <td>";
                htmlAllFields = htmlAllFields + "   " + _value;
                htmlAllFields = htmlAllFields + "  </td>";
                htmlAllFields = htmlAllFields + " <tr>";
            }

            htmlAllFields = htmlAllFields + "</table>";
```

How can I get my label and values ?

Thanks

Comment: `Request.Form` is a collection of all the controls on the page that are submitted.  You can parse that collection on PostBack to get the values of any dynamically created controls.

Comment: It's not clear from your question how you are doing the postback. If you are doing it via an ajax/Jquery post, then add a Class to your dynamic controls and then using jQuery use a class selector ```$('.myclass').each(function(I,obj) { code here });``` syntax will allow you to loop your objectss

Comment: No; is a classic postback  from a <asp:Button> control...

Comment: Always recreate dynamic controls on PostBack (so no `IsPostBack` check). ViewState will take care of the values.